# Why Rglpk_solve_LP() from R needs additional weighting and not only constraints

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

My previous tasks were to solve a binary linear programming problem with very small amount of decision variables.

```
obj = rep(1,times=6)  # objective function with 6 decision variables
```

And of course I added here some constraints (containing the matrix `mat`, the vectors `dir` and `rhs`), defined the types to binary (`types = rep("B",times=6)`) and over `max` I specified if it's
a maximization or minimization. And finally I get the following lines of code.

```
library(Rglpk)
...
res=Rglpk_solve_LP(obj, mat, dir, rhs, types, max)
```

And here my **results were like expected**...

Than there comes the time where I had round about **200 decision variables** in my objective function.

```
obj = rep(1,times=200)  # objective function
...
res=Rglpk_solve_LP(obj, mat, dir, rhs, types, max)
```

And here my problem arised. The solver putted a `$solution` out that's wrong! I controlled my constraints by hand and later by a selfcoded function for reproducibility... `$status = 0` and therefore an optimal solution is found. And that's a little bit confusing to me...

So I tryed a lot and lastly I gave my objective function something like a "**weighting**"...

```
obj_weight = rep(2,times=200)   # standard weighting
obj_weight[1:5] = 4             # positiv emphasis on these decision variables
obj_weight[20:40] = -1          # negativ emphasis on these decision variables
obj_weight[110:140] = -2        # negativ emphasis on these decision variables
obj_weight[...] = ...           # and may be more weights
...
res=Rglpk_solve_LP(obj_weight, mat, dir, rhs, types, max)
```

... and that solved my problem - `$solution` has no violations anymore.

But now I struggle how to implement future projects and for me some questions emerge:

- what's the difference between using only **constraints** and doing additionally **weighting** in the objective function (first trail: *only* constraints vs. second trial: *same* constraints and weighting of objective function)

  - because in the above mentioned example the impact on the solution given by the solver is enormous (only constraints, there is constraint violation and with additional weighting there is no constraint violation)
- at which amount of decision variables it is required to implement a weighting in the objective function
- some additionally issues I'm not aware of?!

I appreciate any suggestions... Many thanks in advance!

**Edit_1**: A small picture to show how I "reused" some of my constraints to be now my weighting for the objective function.

[image]

**Edit_2**:

I have devided my "minimal" example in 4 parts, so that it's a little bit clearer to understand.

- Part 1: Introduction to the problem
- Part 2: Implementing the matrix mat - left hand side of the constraints
- Part 3: Doing the optimization
- Part 4: Looking at the violations (which only occure in `res_1`)

And I know, that my buildup of `mat` is a little bit freaky so please don't be discouraged.

For comparing with the results you only need the first 7 rows of `mat`, because here are the qualifications and preferences of the workers. And for worker_1 you need the constraints defined in *worker_1 (Fri to Sat)* (comment in `mat`) and *worker_2 (Sat to Sun)* (comment in `mat`).

So here is the link to the example:
https://github.com/tueftla1/r-notebooks/blob/main/rglpk.ipynb

Comment: You really don't know the difference between an objective function and a constraint?

Comment: @Erwin Kalvelagen: Interesting how you interpret my question... Perhaps I should clarify a little: First I had an objective function just with ones and a bunch of constraints. And then I had an objective function which puts positiv and negativ emphasis on the decision variables. And this information (how to put emphasis on specific elements in the objective function) before was in my bunch of constraints. So my weighting is an excluded part of my before constraints...

Comment: @Erwin Kalvelagen: I updated my question a little bit for clarification and perhaps you glimpse again at my question... I'm wondering why an LP with constraints provides a solution with constraint violations. And having the "same" LP (with same constraints) with a weighted objective function the solution hasn't constraint violations anymore.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Erwin Kalvelagen: I have now made an reproducible example - see the link at my question...